# find frequency of word from one csv column to other csv column

Tags: python, csv

i am new to python i have two csv file one have contain Bacteria name

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

from collections import Counter
import re
import operator

#Bacteria File Open

Bac = []
with open ("/home/shayez/Desktop/Bacteria.csv", "r") as csv_file1:
    csv_reader1 = csv.reader(csv_file1,delimiter = ',')

    for lines1 in csv_reader1:
        Bac.append(lines1)
       # print(lines1[0])


#Abstract File Open
Abs = []
with open ("/home/shayez/Desktop/Anti.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter = ',')

    for lines in csv_reader:
        Abs.append(lines[2])



abswordlist = []
 for ab in Abs:
 abswordlist.append(Counter(ab.split()))

 #print (abswordlist)

 cntword = Counter(Abs)

 for Bac in Bac:
 print (f"{Bac}:{abswordlist[Bac]}")
```

like this :-

[image]

this is bacteria file which contain approx 2200 bacteria name

the second  file which contain abstract 
Like this :-
[image]

i have to compare word of first bacteria file name to second Abstract column and  count frequency of bacteria into Abstract and save into third csv

Like This :-
[image]

Comment: what have you done so far

Comment: i have extracted first csv into list1 and second into second list2 and try to compare list but i am not success

Comment: ok cool, go ahead and post the code you've got

Comment: import csv
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter
import re
import operator


#Bacteria File Open

Bac = []
with open ("/home/shayez/Desktop/Bacteria.csv", "r") as csv_file1:
    csv_reader1 = csv.reader(csv_file1,delimiter = ',')
    
    for lines1 in csv_reader1:
        Bac.append(lines1)
         
#Abstract File Open
Abs = []
with open ("/home/shayez/Desktop/Anti.csv", "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter = ',')
    
    for lines in csv_reader:
        Abs.append(lines[2])

Comment: I mean post it in your question

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the pandas library to do this task since it seems you will have lots of aggregations to do.

Since you don't provide a [mcve] I had to make one of my own.
So, you have to read your first csv and keep the values as a list. They will later be your columns you will keep.

Then... using this array. I suggest you use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), combined with `split()` and [`Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) (from python collections).
Then, [`join()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) all this using [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html).

```
import pandas as pd

from collections import Counter
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

to_keep = ['LONER', 'I', 'AM']

df = pd.DataFrame({
        'date' : ['some date', 'some_other_date', 'lol date'],
        'garbage' : ['I AM A LONER', 'AND SO AM I LOL', 'some other weird sentence']
    })
print(df.head())
#               date                    garbage
# 0        some date               I AM A LONER
# 1  some_other_date            AND SO AM I LOL
# 2         lol date  some other weird sentence

# Here I am showing you the inside of what I insert into json_normalize.
# It basically counts the word occurrences per line. You split the words,    
# and count the list items using `Counter()`
print(df['garbage'].apply(lambda x:Counter(x.split())))
# 0                {'I': 1, 'AM': 1, 'A': 1, 'LONER': 1}
# 1       {'AND': 1, 'SO': 1, 'AM': 1, 'I': 1, 'LOL': 1}
# 2    {'some': 1, 'other': 1, 'weird': 1, 'sentence'...

# Then, you use the json_normalize() function to turn all your jsons into a big DataFrame. And join the result to the previously created DataFrame.
df = df.join( json_normalize(df['garbage'].apply(lambda x:Counter(x.split()))) )
print(df)
#               date                    garbage    A  ...    sentence  some  weird
# 0        some date               I AM A LONER  1.0  ...         NaN   NaN    NaN
# 1  some_other_date            AND SO AM I LOL  NaN  ...         NaN   NaN    NaN
# 2         lol date  some other weird sentence  NaN  ...         1.0   1.0    1.0

# And keep the first indices, here, only date, in addition of the columns you wished to keep earlier.
final_df = df[ ['date'] + [*to_keep] ]
print(final_df)
#               date  LONER    I   AM
# 0        some date    1.0  1.0  1.0
# 1  some_other_date    NaN  1.0  1.0
# 2         lol date    NaN  NaN  NaN
```